# Text not wrapping in d3 SVG element even when using Bostock's wrap function

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I'm attempting to wrap text in an SVG element using D3.js. I know this is not a feature of SVG, so I am using Mike Bostock's wrap function for wrapping text. However, rather than wrapping the text, calling the function just results in the text being added on top of each other.

Why is this function not wrapping the text as expected and how can I properly update my code so that it will?

The code I have is:

```
      const svg = d3
        .selectAll(".chart")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height) 

      var wrappingTextgroup = svg
        .append("g")

      wrappingTextgroup
        .append('text')
        .attr("x", 50)
        .attr("y", 100)
        .attr('class', "testClass")
        .text("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.")
        .attr('fill', 'black')
        .style('opacity', '1')
        .call(wrap, 100);

function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
      words = text
        .text()
        .split(/\s+/)
        .reverse(),
      word,
      line = [],
      lineNumber = 0,
      lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
      y = text.attr("y"),
      dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy"))
      tspan = text
        .text(null)
        .append("tspan")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", y)
        .attr("dy", dy + "em");        
    while ((word = words.pop())) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text
          .append("tspan")
          .attr("x", 0)
          .attr("y", y)
          .attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em")
          .text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `dy` attribute on your text append here:

```
wrappingTextgroup
.append('text')
.attr("x", 50)
.attr("y", 100)
.attr('dy', 0) // here
.attr('class', "testClass")
.text("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.")
.attr('fill', 'black')
.style('opacity', '1')
```

The wrap function parses that `dy`